# How to bind form in Django when it has others parameters

Tags: python, django, forms, view, model

I'm trying to perform `.is_valid()` after a POST request with my form.

```
form = DrinkForm(request.POST)
```

Like this, the "problem" is that this form has other parameters.

forms.py:

```
class DrinkForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, language, account_id, configurations, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DrinkForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        translation.activate(language)
```

With this, I don't know how to make my form bound (and I can't find any guide or example about this case).

When I print my form called in view with its regular parameters it's everything ok, but if I add `request.POST` I get nothing.

```
form_ok = DrinkForm('english', request.session['account_id'], configurations)  # OK
form_not_ok = DrinkForm(request.POST)  # Needs parameters
form_how_to = DrinkForm('english', request.session['account_id'], configurations, request.POST)  # How to?
```

*EDIT: added form and view codes*

```
def create_drink(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c = {}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        data = DrinkForm.build_create_data(request.POST)
        try:  # Tries to create the new drink
            account = Account.objects.get(id=request.session['account_id'])
            drinks_conf = DrinksConf.objects.get(account_id=request.session['account_id'])
            form = DrinkForm(get_language(request), request.session['account_id'], drinks_conf, request.POST)
            print(form)  # Nothing is printed!
            if form.is_valid():
                print('valid?')  # Not printed!
                with transaction.atomic():
                    stock = DrinkStock.objects.create(account=account, stock=0)
                    Drink.objects.create(account=account, name=data['name'], cost=data['cost'], stock=stock,
                                         stock_by=data['stock_by'])
                return JsonResponse(DRINK_CREATE_SUCCESS)
            else:
                print('oh no not valid')  # Neither printed!! What the..?
                return JsonResponse(form_error_response(form.errors))
        except:  # Unknown exception
            return JsonResponse(UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION)
```

forms.py:

```
class DrinkForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, language, account_id, drinks_conf, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DrinkForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        translation.activate(language)
        self.account_id = account_id  # will be used in the future
        self.drinks_conf = drinks_conf
        options = (
            (1, translation.gettext('Units')),
            (3, translation.gettext('Litters'))
        )
        self.fields['name'] = forms.CharField(
            max_length=100,
            required=True,
            label=translation.gettext('Name'),
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control dynamic_object_submit'})
        )
        self.fields['cost'] = forms.DecimalField(
            max_digits=14,
            decimal_places=2,
            required=True,
            label=translation.gettext('Cost'),
            widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control dynamic_object_submit'})
        )
        self.fields['stock_by'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            required=True,
            label=translation.gettext('Stock/cost by'),
            choices=options,
            widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control dynamic_object_submit'})
        )

    def clean_cost(self):
        if self.drinks_conf.cost_control is True:
            data = self.cleaned_data['cost']
            if data < 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError(translation.gettext("Cost can't be negative"))

    @staticmethod
    def build_create_data(querydict):
        return {
            'name': querydict.get('name', None),
            'cost': querydict.get('cost', None),
            'stock_by': querydict.get('stock_by', None),
        }
```

Comment: The third example (form_how_to) looks like it should work, do you get an error?

Comment: With that example, either I try to `print(form)` or `print(form.is_valid())` I get nothing. Do you think it can be another type of error?

Comment: Nothing as in `None`? Can you add your view to the question

Comment: I mean I can't access `form.is_valid()`. Sure I can add it

Comment: @IainShelvington I added it! Thanks

Comment: Ignore my last answer. Your intention is to have dynamic labels/options based on the passed language?

Comment: No, there is a `ModelChoiceField` based in the account (passed as parameter) that I haven't included in the post in order to save some lines

Comment: Changed my answer. Are you just changing the options in the `ModelChoiceField`?

Comment: Drinks can have a Brand (a `ForeingKey` field), which is a `Select` that will be populated with the brands of the account in session. Your answer is useful and you taught me something new, but I still can't resolve this problem

Comment: What issue do you have now? You should probably use a ModelForm if the form is form creating an instance of a model

Comment: The issue is how do you populate a ModelChoiceField where you populate it based on a id, without initializing a Form/ModelForm, hence you need to pass parameters

Comment: Changing field parameters is fine to do in the `__init__` method even after the form is bound. You can do something like `self.fields['brand'].queryset = queryset_of_brands`, even after the call to `super`. Validation is not done until `is_valid` is called

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gettext_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy) on your field labels to provide translation at request time. Now you don't need to pass the language into your initialization method and the post data should bind correctly since you are not dynamically adding fields

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class DrinkForm(forms.Form):

    name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        required=True,
        label=_('Name'),
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control dynamic_object_submit'})
    )
    cost = forms.DecimalField(
        max_digits=14,
        decimal_places=2,
        required=True,
        label=_('Cost'),
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control dynamic_object_submit'})
    )
    stock_by = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=True,
        label=_('Stock/cost by'),
        choices=(
            (1, _('Units')),
            (3, _('Litters'))
        ),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control dynamic_object_submit'})
    )
```